# groups with prescribed conjugacy class sizes

Tags: group-theory

Given a list of conjugacy class sizes, $1=n_1\leq n_2\leq...\leq n_k$, does there exist a group with exactly $k$ conjugacy classes with sizes $n_k$?  The same question for an infinite list, specifically, $n_k=k$.

Comment: You're asking whether every solution of $\sum kn_k=n$ corresponds to a group of $n$ elements. But there aren't enough groups of $n$ elements to cover all solutions of that equation.

Answer (score 1):

Not necessarily. For example, any group of order $5=1+2(2)$ is cyclic.

Answer (score 0):

Note that one restriction is that the size of a conjugacy class must divide the order of the group. But even with that restriction...let's look at an example. The number of ways to get $8$ by adding $1$s, $2$s, $4$s, and $8$s is $10$ (8; 44; 422; 4211; 41111; 2222; 22211; 221111; 2111111; 11111111), while the number of groups of order $8$ is only $5$ (and three of those groups are abelian, so they fall into the 11111111 category). There just aren't enough groups to go around.